# How do you call a static method on a custom class? JS

Tags: javascript, class, methods, static

In javascript, I've created a class Group that creates an empty array named items and returns it.

But I'm trying to create a static method from(){} that takes an iterable object and creates a new Group from that iterable obj.

I'm trying this.items.push() but its not working how I'd expect it to

```
class Group(){
 constructor(){
   this.items = []
 }
 from(obj){
  for(let item of obj){this.items.push(item)}
 }
}
```

i'd implement it like so:

```
let group = Group.from([10, 11))//random numbers
```

it unfortunately returns the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined (line 37 in function 
Function.from)
```

Comment: *Group* doesn't have a *from* method, instances of *Group* do.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error:

```
class Group(){
```

should be:

```
class Group { // no parameter list here
```

as in the class syntax, the parameters are defined in the constructor function.

Where a constructor adds methods to "class" instances as below, the method is available to instances, not the constructor itself. You you have to create an instance, then call the method:

```js
class Group {
  constructor () {
    this.items = [];
  }
  from (obj) {
    for (let item of obj) {
      this.items.push(item);
    }
  }
}

var group = new Group();
group.from([1,2]);
console.log(group.items); // 1, 2

console.log(typeof Group.from); // undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Although there are drafts for new static syntax on JS classes, you'll currently need to use the prototype for static methods / properties.

```
class Group {
  constructor(){
    this.items = []
  }
}

Group.prototype.from = function(obj){
  var group = new Group;
  for(let item of obj) group.items.push(item);
  return group;
}

let group = aGroudInstance.from([10, 11]);
```

You probably want to simply add the method onto the Group class (object) like so:

```
Group.from = function(...) ...;
```

As it's not actually making use of being a static method, and would unnecesarily require an instance of a `Group` -- unless you used it like so: `Group.prototype.from(...)`.

It's a factory function.

Comment: Thank you for this. I realize now that it was a "this" usage error on my part. I'm working eloquentjavascript.net which is using the latest JS and allows me to declare the method right underneath the constructor! 

I created a temporary group variable as you did and then returned it.